# Python, check if a list contain elements from another list and compare them efficiently

Tags: python

I have created 2 lists, which contain log files coming from different machines.

So I have `machine1` folder that contains `perf_log.txt`, `stress_log.txt` and so on.
Then I have `machine2` folder, that contains the same file names as above. In some cases, I may have logs from one machine but not from the other.

What I did so far, to compare their content, is to parse all the files in one folder, and add the full path to a list, and then do the same with the second folder. Then I would like to compare the correspondent logs (like perf_log.txt), between the 2 machines.

But I end up parsing the first list once, but I have to check every time if the second list contain the entry, and if it does, I have to go and retrieve the index, before I can compare the files. This seems pretty expensive, in the case of many files in a folder

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

path1 = "~/Desktop/machine1/"
path2 = "~/Desktop/machine2/"

os.chdir(path1)
for entry in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    list1.append(entry)

os.chdir(path2)
for entry in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    list2.append(entry)

for logfile in list1:
    if logfile in list2:
        # Retrieve the index of the common file
        item_index = list2.index(logfile)
        # parse files and compare them
        comparefiles(path1 + logfile, path2 + list2[index])
```

How can I simplify this, and try to get to a O(n) complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead of using a list.
So instead of     `list1.append(entry)` you can do `dict[entry] = entry`
This will help in the later part of code where you are doing `if logfile in list2:` which traverses the whole list to find it. Instead you can do `if dict.get(logfile,-1) != -1` to check if the file exists in 2nd path in O(1). You can just pass in the path to your `comparefiles()` method then.

I hope it makes sense.

Here is the code that should work. (I havent tested it though)

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

path1 = "~/Desktop/machine1/"
path2 = "~/Desktop/machine2/"

os.chdir(path1)
for entry in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    dict1[entry] = entry

os.chdir(path2)
for entry in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    dict2[entry] = entry
for key in dict1:
    if dict2.get(key,-1) != -1:
        comparefiles(path1+key,path2+key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since order doesn't matter.

```
list(set(list1) & set(list2))
```

You are performing an intersection operation between the two lists, which are first made to sets. Now you have a list of entries that are in `list1` **AND** in `list2`. After you have a common list of entries you can perform comparisons between these two files.

This is not an O(n) solution, probably a O(nlogn) solution. Still better performing than the code given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `sets` provide O(n) complexity but they would certainly make finding the differences between the two lists easier as you can perform subtraction: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

```
logfiles1 = {}
logfiles2 = {}
in_1_but_not_in_2 = logfiles1 - logfiles2
```

I'm assuming the file names/paths are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get some good improvements if you use numpy and pandas' series.

Before starting, import numpy and pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Now transform your lists into numpy arrays.

```
list1 = np.array(list1)
list2 = np.array(list2)
```

Now you can make use of indexing to find out which files from one group are also in the other.

```
items_in_both = list1[pd.Series(list1).isin(list2)]
```

Now, `items_in_both` contains all items that appear in both lists. With this, you can call your `comparefiles` function once for each element in `items_in_both`.